# buildpublish to a different server

Tags: publish, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to use buildpublisher in the ccnet.config to copy some files over after the build. I am able to do this locally on the server but if I try to copy it over to another server that is on the same network it doesnt go. I think it has to do with security settings but I am not seeing anything in the [Documentation](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Build%20Publisher.html) about setting a user/pass security setting or anything. Any suggestions on what do do?

```
  <buildpublisher>
    <sourceDir>C:\Build\Publish\</sourceDir>
    <publishDir>\\remoteserver\Site</publishDir>
    <cleanPublishDirPriorToCopy>true</cleanPublishDirPriorToCopy>
    <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
    <description>Build publish</description>
  </buildpublisher>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the \remoteserver\Site directory.  Also make sure the user (or service account) that runs the CruisControl.Net service has read/write permissions on the shared directory. We use nant to copy files from Clear Case to another server with this method.